# How to remove rows from a csv file containing unwanted characters using python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a csv file named input. csv
It has a column called "label" 
So I want to remove all the values from label column starting with / character. 
Please give some solutions.

Comment: sudo start working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need remove all rows where `/` starts in column `label`:

```
df1 = df[~df['label'].str.startswith('/')]
```

Comment: I guess above 100k enlightment strikes you, and you can still answer this type of questions in a constructive manner. respect

Comment: @Boud you crushed the `pd.cut` question.. take a look at my answers.  Thought you'd be interested.